# Folder search using os.scandir

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a small Program which basically searches for some mat files in a Network drive. I am using Python3.6 so i have access to `os.scandir()` command which is mentioned to be better than `os.walk().`

But I face a weird Problem, when I run the program for the first time it takes a lot of time to get the data. But when I run the same program after few hours, it works very fast.

Can anyone explain me why this is caused? The following is my code.

Note: I have a very good Internet Speed, so the mapping of Network drive is seamless.

```
class WorkThread(QObject):
    def scantree(self,path):
        try:
            for entry in scandir(path):
                if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
                    yield from self.scantree(entry.path)  # see below for Python 2.x
                else:
                    yield entry
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Excluded file path")

    def searchFiles(self):
        start=time.time()
        ui.progressBar.setValue(0)
        usePATH='V:\Messdatenbank_Powertrain' # Location to the network drive
        os.chdir(usePATH)
        fileLevels = 0
        i=0
        k=0
        tableSize = ui.tableView.width()
        ui.tableView.setColumnWidth(4, int(tableSize/4) + 30 )
        ui.tableView.setColumnWidth(3, int(tableSize/4) + 300 )
        for entry in self.scantree(usePATH):
            if entry.name.endswith('COMPARE.mat') and 'MATLAB_NVH_TOOL' not in entry.path and 'old' not in entry.path and 'MESSDATENBANK' not in entry.path and 'old_' not in entry.path:
                ui.progressBar.setValue(0)
                i=i+1
                fileLevels=0# if 'COMPARE.mat' in f and not 'MIN' in f and not 'MAX' in f / if 'COMPARE.mat' in f )   # if 'COMPARE.mat' in f and not 'MIN' in f and not 'MAX' in f
                fileLevels=(entry.path.split('\\'))                            # Split path string at all '/'
                #print (fileLevels)
                t_row=[QtGui.QStandardItem(str(fileLevels[2])),QtGui.QStandardItem( str(fileLevels[3])),QtGui.QStandardItem(str(fileLevels[4])),QtGui.QStandardItem(str(fileLevels[len(fileLevels)-1])),QtGui.QStandardItem(str(entry.path))]
                ui.tableView.model().appendRow(t_row)
                ui.tableView.model().layoutChanged.emit()
                fileLevels.remove(fileLevels[len(fileLevels)-1])
                tmp_file_levels='\\'.join(fileLevels)
                ui.files.append(tmp_file_levels) # All files path stored here
                ui.file_loc_name.append(entry.path)
                ui.progressBar.setValue(50)
                # Implement try catch blocks
                if str(fileLevels[2]) not in ui.clusterlist:
                    ui.clusterlist.append(str(fileLevels[2]))
                if str(fileLevels[2]) not in ui.enginedict:
                    ui.enginedict[str(fileLevels[2])]=[str(fileLevels[3])]
                else:
                    if str(fileLevels[3]) not in ui.enginedict[str(fileLevels[2])]:
                        ui.enginedict[str(fileLevels[2])].append(str(fileLevels[3]))
                if str(fileLevels[3]) not in ui.measurementdict:
                    ui.measurementdict[str(fileLevels[3])]=[str(fileLevels[4])]
                else:
                    if str(fileLevels[4]) not in ui.measurementdict[str(fileLevels[3])]:
                        ui.measurementdict[str(fileLevels[3])].append(str(fileLevels[4]))                               
                ui.progressBar.setValue(100)
                QApplication.processEvents() 
            else:
                ui.label_7.setText(str(i))
                ui.tableView.model().layoutChanged.emit()
                ui.progressBar.setValue(0)
        end=time.time()
        print(end-start)
        ui.label_2.setText('Update Complete')
        ui.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        print(str(len(ui.files)))
        ui.tableView.resizeColumnToContents (2)
        ui.comboBox.setEnabled(True)
        ui.label_7.setText(str(len(ui.files)))
        ui.comboBox.clear()
        ui.comboBox.addItems(["--Select Cluster--"])
        ui.comboBox.addItems(ui.clusterlist)
        ui.progressBar.setValue(100)
        QApplication.processEvents()
        ui.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)
        ui.pushButton_24.setEnabled(True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[python.org PEP 471 -- os.scandir()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/#notes-on-caching) describes the implementation of `os.scandir`

> `os.scandir` - This new function adds useful functionality and
>   increases the speed of os.walk() by 2-20 times

The difference between the first execution, and the next executions caused by **caching** data during the first execution.

> **Notes on caching**
>
> The DirEntry objects are relatively dumb -- **the name and path
>   attributes are obviously always cached, and the is_X and stat methods
>   cache their values** (immediately on Windows via FindNextFile , **and
>   on first use on POSIX systems via a stat system call**) and never
>   refetch from the system.
>
> For this reason, DirEntry objects are intended to be used and thrown
>   away after iteration, not stored in long-lived data structured and the
>   methods called again and again.
>
> If developers want "refresh" behaviour (for example, for watching a
>   file's size change), they can simply use pathlib.Path objects, or call
>   the regular os.stat() or os.path.getsize() functions which get fresh
>   data from the operating system every call.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why it does that. Actually the Network drive is a database for .mat files. When i open the program i would like to populate a table in my GUI with all the filenames in my Network drive. So is there a better way than os.scandir()

Comment: @ayaan - happy to hear that I answered your question. If so - please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. Regarding the question about *network driver* - `os.scandir docs` specify that it should be fast way to access network drive ("Matt Z: "I used scandir to dump the contents of a network dir in under 15 seconds. 13 root dirs, 60,000 files in the structure. This will replace some old VBA code embedded in a spreadsheet that was taking 15-20 minutes to do the exact same thing.") - how many dirs/files do you have? how much time does it takes for scandir() to run?

Comment: It takes 4 mins around to get the filenames, around 1000 sub_directories and may be 10,000 mat files @Yaron

Comment: @ayaan - 1000 sub dirs & the fact that it is a network drive might be the reason for the 4 minutes. BTW - how much time does it takes, when you are using `os.walk()`?

Comment: it takes 10 mins around, i understand that there are two many files, can't we parallelize the process? @Yaron

Comment: @ayaan - I'm not aware of any better implementation. If you think that a better implementation might be  possible, you might want to ask a new question regarding this issue - "is there any way to improve performance of 1000 sub-dirs/10,000 files, on a network drive"